# TFS Online 2012 / How to Deploy Custom Check-In Policies

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools, checkin-policy

I am going to create a custom check-in policy and I'm using `TFS Online` and `VS2012`. I could find a [video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg602484.aspx) describing [this procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) but it's rather old documentation. I've tried to find clear documentation on how to accomplish this in my specific environment to no avail.

1. Are any new ways of accomplishing this in the environment I'm working on `TFS Online` / `VS2012`.
2. Is there any gotcas I should be aware of?
3. Should I consider looking into `TFS PowerTools`?

Comment: At least I found out the correct registry key is now: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies

Comment: For what I understand this is not possible on Team Foundation **Service**. The video you refer to should still apply to TFS 2012 (non-service) though.

Comment: It works on Visual Studio Online as well, they're executed on the client. The checkin policy is dependent on the version of Visual Studio so you need to build one for each version of Visual Studio (they're not server specific).